# Move sprite relative to another sprite that's moving in Spritekit

Tags: sprite-kit

I'm trying to make an infinite scrolling game. I have buildings and my hero is jumping on the roofs. I'd like to add enemies patrolling on the rooftops. I have positioned the enemies on the rooftops and they are scrolling with the buildings.

That's how my buildings spawn and move:

```
public func spawnBuilding() {

    buildingNode = BuildingSprite.newInstance()

    let moveBuilding = SKAction.moveTo(x: -self.frame.width, duration: buildingSpeed)
    let removeBuilding = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    buildingNode.run(SKAction.sequence([moveBuilding, removeBuilding]))

    addChild(buildingNode)

}
```

Enemies:

```
    public func addCoptoScene(position: CGPoint){

    copNode = CopSprite.newInstance(position: position)

    let moveCop = SKAction.moveTo(x: -self.frame.width, duration: buildingSpeed)
    let removeCop = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    copNode.run(SKAction.sequence([moveCop, removeCop]))

    addChild(copNode)
}
```

The position CGPoint is at the top middle of each building. 
I have this for the movement for my enemies:

```
public func move(distance: CGFloat){

    let randomX = CGFloat(Int.random(min: -1, max: 1))
    let vector = CGVector(dx: randomX * distance / 2, dy: 0)

    let moveBy = SKAction.move(by: vector, duration: 1)

    run(SKAction.sequence([moveBy, moveBy.reversed()]))  
}
```

The distance would be the width of my buildings. I know that's not correct, I will have to find a way to limit my enemy movement to the width of the roof.

And that's where I stopped and ran out of ideas.

As you probably can see, this is my very first game. Sorry for the bad code, I'm trying to improve.

Thank you

Comment: Do not move your buildings, move the entire node the buildings are attached to

Comment: ^^^ Attach your buildings, enemies, and buildings to an SKNode that is separate from your character. Then, all you have to do is move that SKNode. You can also move your enemies along the rooftops of the buildings without having to do a bunch of complicated math.

Comment: thank you guys, im currently implementing your idea!